# Hide Fatal Error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with hiding Fatal Errors from my wordpress site display.

I tried using the following in wp-config.php but it didn't work:

```
error_reporting(0); 
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I still see this fatal error being displayed.

I also have this in my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Currently I have an error_log in the wordpress root. I do want to know what the errors are, just don't want them to be displayed to end users, because that would expose my cp username.

Comment: Maybe...just maybe you want to fix the error instead of hidding the error....

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors','off');` Add this to you header.php file in the theme folder.

Comment: Of course the first instinct is to want to fix the error. But I don't need to fix that error, everything is working fine. Its just that the error just comes up.

Comment: It's not working fine if you have fatal errors.

Comment: I get what you saying, but the whole site works fine. Its only when someone tries to access site.com/wp-content/something/something-else/functions.php then can the fatal error be seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try inserting this in your index.php

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

or this in .htaccess

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

or just fix them :)

Comment: You would be better off using header.php rather than index.php as what about single post pages etc? The error would not be suppressed on these.

Comment: kind of strange, when I did error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); in header.php, the error still showed up. But when I put in index.php, it worked, a blank page showed up.

Comment: Every request in wordpress is processed by index.php.

Comment: just wanna check, so my error_log in the root will still be able to reflect errors if any, right?

Comment: the htaccess commands hiding the error, but it is throwing a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good thing to hide errors. You should fix it. This error is not related to Wordpress, it's a PHP error.

You have two options:

- disable the error reporting in php settings (file php.ini on the server) and put: "display_errors" to "off"
- or add a .htaccess file to your wordpress directory (or modify it if it already exists).
  You should add those lines in it:

  php_flag display_errors off

  php_flag html_errors off

*Please for the second solution you should check if the .htaccess is in override mode (so you need an access to the server configuration files.*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, tried the php_flag display_errors off & php_flag html_errors off, but something went wrong with the site after that, whole site faced 500 internal server error

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way, but thanks so much for all of your suggestions, I got to learn new stuff while trying out the suggestions.

In the end I went to my Cpanel-> php.ini QuickConfig -> under display errors, I simply selected the radio button 'off'

And everything worked.

Thanks!